# Flutter - pop up notification

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can someone explain me how to make notification to pop up on screen? 
By now notification is only displayed on notification list.

It would be helpful to me if you would send me an example.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SnackBar widget for popup notification.

```
ScaffoldState sState = Scaffold.of(context); 
sState.showSnackBar( 
    SnackBar( 
        content: Text("Hi Im snackbar!!!"), 
        action: SnackBarAction(
             label: 'Dismiss', 
            onPressed: () { 
                sState.hideCurrentSnackBar(); 
            }
        )
    ) 
);
```

But your app needs to be using the Scaffold widget so that it has the snackbar.
Watch this video you might find it helpful: You can watch this video: https://youtu.be/u9KoFtu0HEY